# How do big rocks split in half?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, geophysics, nature

So, recently I was on a trip in which I could observe a lot of huge rocks (1 to 20 meters in diameter), and I found odd how in several occasions rocks would be split in two parts, with a neat division.
An instance of what I am talking about is given in [google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=rock%20split%20in%20half&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig3f2vnIniAhXL-qQKHXTSBRUQ_AUIDigB&biw=1517&bih=640).

I was wondering how such "neat" splitting can happen: is it uniquely the result of impacts with other rocks or can it be caused also by thermic shock or some other mechanism?

My impression is that an impact with the exact energy to split the rock in half (and not crush it in many pieces) could be even more rare than a fluctuation of thermal nature so extreme to split the boulder, but I could be wrong and this thermal splitting could just be too unlikely (like finding all molecules of a roomful of gas in the same spot).

However especially in those cases in which the split rock is not surrounded by other fragments I would tend to say that the splitting should not be due to an impact. But again, I could be wrong.

Summing up, the question is: which between impact, thermal shock and any other explanation should be considered the main responsible for the split boulders that can be found around the world? (and how do other factors compare to the main one?)

Comment: That is an awful lot of seperate questions!

Comment: Some of the question marks are just to propose my own hypotheses. There are basically two questions: how does the splitting happen? and what can we say about the rate at which it happens? Both these two questions address the same problem: understanding the splitting of boulders. Therefore I would say my inquiry is well posed. The additional question marks are to make the matter less vague.

Comment: The rate question is rather interesting.  Off hand, I'm thinking there may be some selection bias involved.  There's an awful lot of rocks out there, every last one of them broke at some point.  There's certainly some [incredible](https://www.huffpost.com/entry/getting-the-most-out-of-a-visit-to-bryce-canyon-national_b_59485e43e4b0961faacbe625?guccounter=1&guce_referrer=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS8&guce_referrer_sig=AQAAACU0Z1PDNNX6EVMhmlvt4JTQBCLbcG1lm1JQuXkUZRk5n-6XLw8EzcZ-eXHeop_XRt-ZBsK4gfseWPCJWjs-kTsscWQJx84pQuoHrkU0sW6ERs9xVmcihEpU2zwZeB4b6mvL--wtJCHToSaqYzddDORC9c_2hJo85-JjlO7j1OVH)

Comment: .. looking rocks out there!

Comment: This might be better-suited for [earthscience.SE].

Comment: Some rocks split easily along fracture lines or layers depending how they were made.

Comment: @Aaron-Stevens and other administrators, please note that I edited the question as suggested. I guess it would be ok to reopen it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer one part of the question and invite others to add to this.

Rocks are brittle, which means that they tend to fracture when struck. As in any brittle material, the fracture usually begins at a pre-existing crack in the rock that is close to the impact point.

A fracture will be self-propagating if the energy required to create a pair of free surfaces along the crack path is supplied by strain energy that is stored in the material. Since most old rocks at the earth's surface were originally formed deep underground, it is the usual thing for them to contain significant amounts of residual compressive stress that was locked into their microstructure when they either solidified from melt or underwent recrystallization during metamorphosis underground.

Once exposed in a large solid mass at the surface, it's then common for the rock mass to crack apart in order to relieve those frozen-in stresses. This is especially true for granitic rocks, in which the exposed rock mass exfoliates in huge slabs- Yosemite valley being a prime example- leaving rounded domes of granite behind.

This means it is possible with a little luck to neatly split a boulder in half if it has residual stresses in it and if it has a pre-existing crack in it.